# How do I test my Unity project for IOS with my IPhone?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I creating the project for IOS device with Unity.
I want to do prototype test of the project with my IPhone.
So, I built this project with Unity, and tried to build the file outputed from Unity with xcode.

But, error happened as this image:
[xcode-versionError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj177.png)

I thought that my Xcode version is old(Version 6.4). So, I tried to update the Xcode with App store.
But, updation was failed because of my OS version(Yosemite 10.10.4)

The upgradation of OS requires long time, I think.
So, I seek the another way of building.

For example, I think building Android application is as follows.
1. Transmit the 'zip-file' including 'exe-file' to my device.
2. Install the application from the 'zip-file'

Is there such a method as IOS?
I appreciate it if anyone tell me the method to do prototype test with my IPhone.

Comment: I believe you need Xcode 7.3 minimum for recent versions of Unity. That error is telling you there's no device to run on. Your phone may be too old, or you're not signing the application correctly. I'm pretty sure you need xCode 7+ to self-sign your app without a developer account and a provisioning profile. You do still need an Apple ID.

Comment: Seems like your device is not properly connected or recognized by the OS. What I did when I was testing an iOS build was to first open iTunes on the mac and let it find the device. Then the device was succesfully recognized on Xcode too

Comment: I connected my device and open iTunes. But iTunes didn't recognized my device. Is that cause this problem?

Comment: What is your device? What OS is on it? If iTunes can't see it and you don't see it in the devices window on xCode then you won't be able to use it to run your app.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to release it directly because I gave up verifying the application on the actual machine.

You tried to answer, but I'm sorry.